# PhpMyAdmin do not update correctly (AWS - EC2)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have tried to install and/or updated phpMyAdmin three times under a Linux Amazon AMI image with Apache server in Amazon EC2, and I don't get to have the last version installed.

This is what I have done to install version 4.1.14:

> 1. cd /var/www/html
> 2. wget
>      http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.1.14/phpMyAdmin-4.1.14-all-languages.tar.gz
> 3. tar -xzvf phpMyAdmin-4.1.14-all-languages.tar.gz -C /var/www/html
> 4. mv phpMyAdmin-4.1.14-all-languages phpmyadmin
> 5. rm -rf phpMyAdmin-4.1.14-all-languages.tar.gz
> 6. adduser phpmyadmin
> 7. passwd phpmyadmin
> 8. chown -R phpmyadmin.apache phpmyadmin/
> 9. cd phpmyadmin
> 10. mkdir config
> 11. chmod o+rw config
> 12. sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config/config.inc.php
>
>     Note: Before re-installing I copy the config.inc.php in a  directory,and 
>             after the installation I restore it from  /config.inc.php
>             config/config.inc.php) sudo chmod o+w config/config.inc.php service
> 13. httpd restart

When opening http:///phpmyadmin/, I'm always getting: Version 2.11.11.3
and an old style main page of phpmyadmin.

How can I update phpMyAdmin to the last version (in this case, 4.1.14, last stable version)?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Did you try from different browser?

Comment: Did you check the Apache config? It could be that there is a baked in `phpmyadmin` alias in the Apache config that would override you loading the installed version in a directory.

Comment: Why do you think you need phpmyadmin?

Comment: I cleared the browser cache. JakeGould: I also have tried in Chrome, Firefox and IE. 
I don't think I need phpmyadmin, I just like it.

Comment: @villamejia, try to rename `phpmyadmin` directory to another name (for example `php-my-admin`), then try to go `http://your.web.site/php-my-admin/`.

Comment: @JakeGould. The only reference I see in Apache config is in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf:  
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">Allow from 127.0.0.1</Directory>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

But even commenting all the lines in this file, and clearing my browser cache, nothing seems to change.

Comment: @villamejia Check out my answer. That config is 100% exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster shared this Apache config this in the comments:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
# Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

That’s your problem. You are trying to install phpMyAdmin manually in the main `/var/www/html` directory.  But this Apache config has three aliases that would override that. The phpMyAdmin in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` is actually the standard RPM package install location.

So if you want to you can just comment out those `Alias` lines like this. Heck, comment out the `<Directory>` stuff as well:

```
# <Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
# Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all Allow from 127.0.0.1
# </Directory>
# Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
# Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
# Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Restart Apache and then go to your URL of:

```
http://the_url_of_your_site/phpmyadmin/
```

And now the upgraded version you installed should load as expected.

The other alternative is to rename `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` to something like `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin4` to get around that `Alias`.  But you don’t need the `Alias` if you are installing directly into the web root of your server.

**EDIT:** And if you want to upgrade the version of `phpmyadmin` in `/usr/share`, then keep those `Alias` directives in place but use the following modified instructions. Please double-check these before running:

> 1. cd /usr/share
> 2. sudo mv phpmyadmin phpmyadmin-OLD
>      NOTE: This is a backup of your old phpmyadmin just in case.
>      Feel free to delete this `phpmyadmin-OLD` when you are sure you are in good shape
>      with the new phpmyadmin.
> 3. sudo wget
>      https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.1/phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-all-languages.tar.gz
> 4. sudo tar -xzvf phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-all-languages.tar.gz -C /usr/share
> 5. sudo mv phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-all-languages phpmyadmin
> 6. sudo rm phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-all-languages.tar.gz
> 7. sudo adduser phpmyadmin
> 8. sudo passwd phpmyadmin
> 9. sudo chown -R phpmyadmin:apache phpmyadmin/
> 10. cd phpmyadmin
> 11. mkdir config
> 12. chmod o+rw config
> 13. sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config/config.inc.php
>        NOTE: Before re-installing I copy the config.inc.php in a  directory,and 
>              after the installation I restore it from  /config.inc.php
>              config/config.inc.php) sudo chmod o+w config/config.inc.php service
> 14. sudo httpd restart

Just please note, there are a few things that are “wonky” but not dangerous about your instructions. For example, there was no `sudo` set before many commands. Maybe that was because it was in `/var/www/html` but I added `sudo`.  Also your `chown` was 100% wrong with `chown -R phpmyadmin.apache` when that should be `chown -R phpmyadmin:apache`.

Comment: Understood. So for solving this issue, I will delete the /var/www/html/. What do I have to do to update phpmyadmin in /usr/share/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Deleting the /var/www/html/phpmyadmin version of PHP is not a great idea yet. I would test what I wrote first to make sure. But I modified your instructions to shift the upgrade to `/user/share`. Basically 100% the same as what you did, but in `/usr/share` instead of `/var/www/html`.

Comment: I had not realized these two places where phpmyadmin could be installed. As the answer says, /usr/share is the standard RPM package install location; the other /var/www/http/ is the location where the user can install it manually without using YUM. Now, when you try to update phpmyadmin using YUM, it says that no updates are available. I think this is the reason why JakeGould proposes a manual installation in /user/share.

Comment: @villamejia You are mixing things up: Typically the phpMyAdmin that is stored in repositories is an older version. Repositories like YUM are not cutting edge. So `2.11.11.3` is just the most “updated” version you will get for now. So if you want to update manually, just do in in `/usr/share`. The YUM repo keeps track of phpMyAdmin it installed differently but I would not worry about it.